# dagger2 cannot find symbol

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm following the *Dagger2* sample of *TODO* app but encounted with 2 errors.

Error1: can't find symbol `DaggerNetComponent`. (Which is actually there)
Error2: `Sharedpreference` can't be provided without @provider-annotated method.(Which I think results from error1)

And here's my long but simple code:
Three modules:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final Application mApplication;

    AppModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }
}

@Module
public class LoadingModule {
    public final LoadingContract.View mView;

    public LoadingModule(LoadingContract.View mView) {
        this.mView = mView;
    }

    @Provides
    LoadingContract.View provideLoadingContractView() {
        return mView;
    }
}

@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }
}
```

And two components:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
}

@FragmentScoped
@Component(dependencies = NetComponent.class, modules = LoadingModule.class)
public interface LoadingComponent {
    void inject(LoadingActivity loadingActivity);
}
```

I get NetComponent in MyApplication:

```
mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .netModule(new NetModule())
                .build();
```

and LoadingComponent in LoadingActivity:

```
DaggerLoadingComponent.builder()
                .netComponent(((MyApplication)getApplication()).getNetComponent())
                .loadingModule(new LoadingModule(loadingFragment))
                .build()
                .inject(this);
```

The only thing that I want `LoadingComponent` to inject is `LoadingPresenter`.

Also in `LoadingActivity`:

```
@Inject LoadingPresenter mLoadingActivityP;
```

And this is how the `LoadingPresenter` constructed:

```
public class LoadingPresenter implements LoadingContract.Presenter {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private LoadingContract.View loadingView;

    @Inject
    public LoadingPresenter(LoadingContract.View loadingView, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
        this.loadingView = loadingView;
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
    }

    @Inject
    void setupListeners() {
        loadingView.setPresenter(this);
    }

    public boolean checkLoginStatus() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("loginStatus", false);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
    }
}
```

End of my program.

It has been annoying me for several days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you might need to set `public` accessibility to all methods in your modules

Comment: @Cheskos I tried but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding your project. Sometimes helps

Comment: @Cheskos  Didn't work neither ....

Comment: try creating your Components with Autodagger https://github.com/lukaspili/Auto-Dagger2

Comment: taking a look at your error, are you sure you really need Dagger for injecting SharedPreferences? Dagger is useful when instantiating custom dependencies. If you need an instance of SharedPrefs just call `getSharedPreferences()` manually

Comment: @Cheskos Yeah, but I'm learning and I think by resolving this error I can get better understanding of Dagger2. Thanks for help .

Comment: Dagger is tricky to learn, and has some implementation issues such as yours (Class not found when it's there). I think you can still get a hold of it by taking out the NetComponent

Comment: I really suggest you use AutoDagger, it helped me understand it as well

Comment: @Cheskos OK I'll try it. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Sure. Im trying to build me reputation lol so I willl keep trying to help you... you say that you get two errors, but in my experience they do not happen simultaneously, in which cases are you getting them?

Comment: @Cheskos There's an answer that helped, but thanks anyway. And I don't know about the reputation. If there's something I can do to build you reputation, tell me and I'm glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the causality of your errors backwards.  The `Dagger*` classes are the final output of the annotation processor.  Because you had an error in your graph, the Dagger processor couldn't complete, so the output was missing.

The second error is saying that you are requesting `SharedPreferences` from within a component that doesn't have it bound.  Because you've chosen component dependencies rather than subcomponents, all of the bindings from your dependencies **are not inherited**.  In order for your `LoadingComponent` to use bindings from `NetComponent` they must be exposed on the component interface.  Adding `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();` to `NetComponent` or switching to subcomponents should fix your problem.

See the [`@Component` docs](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html) and the [page on subcomponents in the user's guide](http://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there's another problem... Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981293/dagger2-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded if you're not busy?