# dagger2 GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, dependency-injection, garbage-collection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm following the *Dagger2* sample of *TODO* app but encounted with OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. Along with it are 600+ warning likes:
*warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class (org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage$StateSaver$1) that doesn't come with an associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner class.*


Here's my code: [dagger2 cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958414/dagger2-cannot-find-symbol) ,where I got my previous problem solved with help of gk5885. Thanks to you  again :-).

Just after I add `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences()` to `NetComponent` and rebuild, the program compiles for 9 minutes and end up throwing that error. But the time to compile the previous version of my app without *Dagger2* is seconds, on account of which I'm pretty sure *Dagger2* caused this error. But I don't know why and how to solve this problem. 

And my vm size: -Xms256m -Xmx1280m. I think it's more than enough. 

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: In fact before I rebuild, I got duplicate file copied in apk error. And I solved it by add this in gradle:

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    }
```

Maybe I should show my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'me.yokeyword:indexablestickylistview:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.11'
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2' // dagger2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2' // dagger2
    compile project(':ToggleButtonLib')
    compile project(':IMKit')
}
```

Sorry for so many descriptions....

Comment: I also ran into this. I don't recall exactly so can't guarantee it will work, but try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: @Cheskos It doesn't work...

Comment: I think you will need to increase your heapsize to 512 or 1024

Comment: @Cheskos Well, I wait 20 minutes for stoping the building process and yet it's still running.... Maybe I'm not qualified to use Dagger2.

Comment: This is definitely strange.  I did notice that your version of Dagger2 is pretty out of date.  2.5 is the latest at the moment.  It might be worth seeing if you're not just hitting some bug that we've since forgotten about.

Comment: `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2' // dagger2` should be `apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2' // dagger2`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @gk5885 @Cheskos Changing `compile` to `apt` solved my problem. Maybe I missed the part of the code in User's Guide to correctly include `dagger-compiler`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case I added the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2' // dagger2
```

to

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2' // dagger2
```

Because you're currently including the entire dagger2 compiler into your project, and that includes Guava and all kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

In my case killing gradle, then cleaning the project fixed the issue.

Perform `./gradlew --stop` followed by `./gradlew clean`.